# WRONG LINE LENGHT shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0.5 draws more than half of the circle

Tags: swift, animation, uikit, core-animation, cashapelayer

I want the line to end at the top with shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 1.0 and get a circle. the line must end here
but she goes on, it just can't be seen

[full circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jccdM.png)

when i specify a value of 0.5 i want to get half of the circle but i get much more

[half circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RI5OO.png)

My code:

**View**

```
    public func createCircleLine(progress: CGFloat, color: UIColor, width: CGFloat) {
    let radius = (min(bounds.width, bounds.height) - circleLineWidth) / 2
    let center = min(bounds.width, bounds.height) / 2

    let bezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: center, y: center),
                                  radius: radius,
                                  startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2,
                                  endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi,
                                  clockwise: true)

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = bezierPath.cgPath
    shapeLayer.fillColor = nil
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = circleProgressLineColor.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = circleLineWidth
    shapeLayer.lineCap = .round
    shapeLayer.strokeEnd = progress
    layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
}
```

**ViewController**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var progressView: CircleProgressView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(false)
    progressView.createCircleLine(progress: 1.0, color: .green, width: 10)
} }
```

I don’t understand why I can’t get the correct line length, the coordinates are correct

can i get the correct line length without CABasicAnimation ()?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `endAngle` of your circle to `3 * CGFloat.pi / 2`, so it is a complete cycle with no overlapping. The current circle you have has `π/2 (90 degrees)` overlap

```
let bezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: center, y: center),
                                      radius: radius,
                                      startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2,
                                      endAngle: 3 * CGFloat.pi / 2,
                                      clockwise: true)
```